# Go to the last worksheet whose name contains string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of dynamically created worksheets in my workbook that all contain the phrase "Roster" in their name. I am trying to activate the last of these worksheets, but I can't figure out how to get the ***last*** sheet. Using this:

`if Worksheets(i).Name Like "*Roster*" Then`

I can loop through the worksheets and perform some actions on ***all*** the sheets that contain that substring in their names, but how do I just perform actions on only the ***last*** of these?

Comment: `I have a bunch of dynamically created worksheets in my workbook that ALL CONTAIN the phrase "Roster" in their name` If all contain the same name then why search? Will there be any worksheets which may not have that word? If not then simply get and use the last worksheet? `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)` will do the job.

Comment: There are other sheets that are not dynamically created. Those do not have "Roster" in their names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps loop over the worksheets backwards and exit the loop after the first match:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = Worksheets.Count to 1 Step -1
    If Worksheets(i).Name Like "*Roster*" Then
        ' do the stuff
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```